# exclude flutter export from import suggestions

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

I often times import `cupertino.dart` instead of `material.dart` when having to import widgets because its the first suggested options.
Its not a real problem but for the sake of consistency I want to prevent importing `cuppertino.dart` so it is not listed in the import suggestions and only use `widgets.dart` or `material.dart` instead.

Is there a way to configure Android Studio or Dart Analyzer to prevent `cuppertino.dart` to show in suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems no, but there is a workaround: You can write a linter to examine your code and warn (or error) whenever you see imports of `cupertino.dart`. That linter can even automatically correct the code (by replacing cupertino with material).

Some methodology thoughts: I often want something to be *automatically* performed ("import material not cupertino" in your case); but later I realized it is hard or not exist yet, but some *verifier* is good enough ("manually import; but warn if you import the wrong one").

Answer (score 1):

You can create an export file with your exports inside and call this file afterwards.

For example create an `exportsFile`:

```
export 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

And now call this file when you wants:

```
import 'exportsFile.dart';
```